# Language not Changing above API Level 24

Tags: android, localization

I am facing problem about Localization in Android app. I am getting Fine result below Version 23.Here I am Using 2 Languages English And Arabic. But Above 24 Version Do not Show Arabic Language.After i put the OnAttachedWindow Method the Layout Direction has been Changed.but Language Still same. Please Help Me..

This is LocaleHelper  Class.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);

        return context;
    }


    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
             updateResources(context, language);
        }else{
            updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
        }

    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Log.d("LocaleHelper", "language above 24: "+language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Log.d("LocaleHelper", "language below 24: "+language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }  
}




Called these 2 Method in My Main Activity Also


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(
                    "ar".equals(LocaleHelper.getLanguage(this)) ?
                            View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL : View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
    }
```

Comment: where is your onConfigurationChnaged method?

Comment: I didnt put anywhere.but working well below 24 version

Comment: I am wondering how come you want it to show Arabic, but yet you are passing "en" in the `onAttach` method?